Show that function is continuous in $x=1$
What would be a correct way to show that the function
$$
f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\qquad f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}, & x\neq 1\\2, & x=1\end{cases}
$$
is continuous in $x=1$?
First observation is that if I define $$g\colon\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}\to\mathbb{R},\qquad g(x):=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1},$$
then, since
$$
\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}=x+1,
$$
it is also obvious that $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$: Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary, then choose $\delta=\varepsilon$ and we have that
$$
\vert g(x)-g(x_0)\vert=\vert x+1-(x_0+1)\vert=\vert x-x_0\vert<\delta=\varepsilon.
$$
And it is also clear that $f$ is the extension of $g$ from $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ since $f_{|\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}}=g$.
It is also clear that $\lim_{x\to 1}(x+1)=2$.
Now let $x_0=1$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Then I can again choose $\delta=\varepsilon$ and from $\vert x-1\vert<\delta$ one gets
$$
\vert f(x)-f(1)\vert=\vert g(x)-2\vert=\vert x+1-2\vert=\vert x-1\vert<\delta=\varepsilon.
$$
Hence $f$ is continuous in $x=1$.
Would that be the correct (complete) proof?
Or is it enough to say that $\lim_{x\to 1}g(x)=2$?

Just plot a graph when $x\neq1$, then cover it with $(1, 2)$.

I think it really enough to show that $f(x) = x+1$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, thus $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, and in particular at $x = 1$.

Okay that would mean to show that $f(x)=x+1$ is continuous, say, by epsilon-delta

@selector Yes if that is the definition you're working with (for this $f$, $\varepsilon = \delta$ suffices).
